# How to diagnose AJAX error which is not throwing any error messages?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following part of ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input#dodaj").click(function(){
        var s = $("form input#zad").val();
        var str = "<li>"+s+"</li>";
        $.ajax( {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://lesni.org/kss/dodaj_zadanie.php",
            data: { 
                pid: ($(this).attr('alt')),
                zad: encodeURI(s)},
            error: function( err ){ alert(err); }
                }
             ).done(function(){
                $("ul#zadania").append(str);
                $("form input#zad").val(" ");
            });
        });     
    });
```

Note: The page loading the code above is from a URL like `http://lesni.org/some/page`, and so the Same Origin Policy isn't an issue.

But it does not seem to work and I don't know why.

The PHP file it is calling is correct. When I type manually in browser:

```
http://lesni.org/kss/dodaj_zadanie.php?pid=1&zad=abc
```

it works correctly (adds record to database). But the ajax code is not working. And it throws no error or I don't know if it throws any error...

So the question is: how can I diagnose this part of AJAX code to know what's wrong. I also tried the `POST` version, with no effect.

Comment: Use FireBug or DeveloperTools and check the Network traffic

Comment: A starting point is using the information the `error` callback gives you. `error: function( err ){ alert(err); }` will not give you any useful information, as the first argument to the [`error` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is the jQuery XHR object. The second and third args are much more useful.

Comment: Btw.. you have to pass the GET params in the uri and not over data field

Comment: Chrome: CTRL+SHIFT+I opens dev tools. Hit ESC, console pops up at the bottom (useful, prints errors when HTTP requests return an error code). Click the "Network" icon at the top. From the menu bar directly above the console, click "XHR". You can now see immediately everything that happens with your AJAX calls.

Comment: @Philipp: You can use `data` with `GET` requests, that's not a problem. [See the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax), jQuery will append the data (properly encoded) to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying `data` like this:

```
data: { 
    pid: ($(this).attr('alt')),
    zad: encodeURI(s)
}
```

When you pass an *object* to jQuery via `data`, you **don't** need (or want) to encode it. (You only do that with a string.) jQuery does that for you. (If you *did* want to encode it, you'd want `encodeURIComponent`, not `encodeURI`). So you'll end up with entities that are double-encoded, and thus won't work corerctly.

That should be:

```
data: { 
    pid: ($(this).attr('alt')),
    zad: s
}
```

(You also don't need the parens around the value of the `pid`, but they're harmless so I've left them.)

---

But answering the question

> How to diagnose AJAX error which is not throwing any error messages?

...you do that by

- Looking at the Network tab in any decent browser's development tools, which shows you *exactly* what it sent to the server and what it got back.
- Using server-side debugging (either proper debugging, or by dumping out things to a log) to look at *exactly* what got received by the server.
- Looking at server-side logs to ensure that the correct resource got requested.

...and so on.

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems to work. I deleted `encodeURI` and it seems to start working. Thanks!

Comment: @Gacek: Probably double-encoding something. I'm glad that sorted it!